# Start android project activity from integrated flutter module?

Tags: android, flutter, android-activity

I have an android app, I integrated a flutter module into it based on https://docs.flutter.dev/development/add-to-app/android/project-setup.

I managed to get calling flutter activity working, even sending extra data with intent and getting response data from flutter too.

What I want to do is the equivalent of calling startActivity(intent), just from my flutter module.
How could I achieve this? Is my only way is deeplinking?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make this work by using the package "android_intent_plus". From there, all I had to do was use this code:

```
var intent = AndroidIntent(
  package: "my.custom.package",
  componentName: "my.custom.package.MyAndroidActivity",
  arguments: {
    "DATA_KEY": "Data to send",
  },
);
await intent.launch();
```

However, this solution is not perfect as of date, because I cannot receive result this way.